# How can I make prepasted wallpaper stick better?

Tags: wallpaper

We bought some roles of prepasted wallpaper to use as a border in a nursery. This was our first time ever putting up any sort of wallpaper; I don't think we did it exactly right (I don't think we got the paper wet enough before sticking it to the wall in some spots).

After it dried, we were actually pretty pleased with the results but noticed a couple of places where the edges don't stick like they should. Some of these spots don't look too bad, but I'm worried they'll get worse over the next several years if I don't address them.

Can we just "paint" them with water and re-press the spots that aren't sticking?

I added some pictures below - sorry they're so large, I don't know how to resize them on here.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using wallpaper paste when hanging it will make it stick better.

From the photo it looks like the paper is too short in the corner.

To fix peeling paper use dilute white (PVA) glue.

Probably the you would have benefited from doing more preparation to wall surface too (sand it and size it). it looks very lumpy.

http://homeguides.sfgate.com/need-size-walls-hanging-wallpaper-77898.html